# How to detect a type is pointer in preprocessor of C?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

Is there a way to detect whether a type is pointer in preprocessor of C?

Suppose its name is **IS_POINTER**. What the final result I want may looks like:

```
#define DATA_STRUCTURE(KEY_T)

#if IS_POINTER(KEY_T)
/* do something */
#endif
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you know if it's a pointer or not since you wrote the code?  I'm not sure I understand what you're really trying to accomplish.  What is your goal in asking this question?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The pre-processor knows very little about C and actually executes at a point in time where the C code isn't even parsed. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you might have some luck with C11's [generic selection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic).

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  Why would you need to know about this?  What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor has no notion of types, you cannot write such a macro that can be used in a `#if` directive.

Conversely, you can use some non-portable built-in functions to write an expression that does check if a given object is a pointer or something else.

Here is a macro to perform a static assertion that `a` is an array:

```
#define assert_array(a) \
     (sizeof(char[1 - 2 * __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(&(a)[0]))]) - 1)
```

It can be used with `gcc` and `clang`.  I use it to make the `countof()` macro safer:

```
#define countof(a)  ((ssize_t)(sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)) + assert_array(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `typeof(expr)`, which may help you in your task. It doesn't exactly tell you something is a pointer, but perhaps you could use it in comparisons:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

Comment: Is `typeof` a preprocessor construct, or a compiler construct?